# Date constructor: numeric arguments vs. string argument giving different dates in some cases

Tags: javascript, date, constructor

First of all, I think timezone probably has something to do with this. I'm in EST/EDT. Also, I'm testing this on chromium 17 / linux.

Now, let's say I create two dates like this:

```
// December 5

dateFromNumbers = new Date(2020, 11, 5);
dateFromString = new Date("2020-12-5");
```

It seems these dates should have identical timestamps, and they do:

```
+dateFromNumbers == +dateFromString; // true
```

...at least in this case. But in some cases, they don't:

```
// December 15

dateFromNumbers = new Date(2020, 11, 15);
dateFromString = new Date("2020-12-15");

+dateFromNumbers == +dateFromString; // false
```

What's going on here?

```
dateFromNumbers; // Tue Dec 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
dateFromString;  // Mon Dec 14 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Looks like `dateFromString` is 5 hours earlier than `dateFromNumbers` in this case (EST is GMT - 5, I'm sure it's related somehow).

It seems to affect the ends of months October through December. Here's a fiddle that makes it easy to see which days differ (unless you are red-green colorblind, in that case it may be difficult to see, my apologies).

http://jsfiddle.net/9gBfX/

What gives?

---

Notes:

- You can set your system timezone to EST/EDT to see the jsfiddle example as I'm seeing it.
- Date's month numbers are zero-based; the `11` is not a typo.
- This issue appears in every year that I checked.

Comment: In your second case date is November 15, 2020 and December 15, 2020. is it a typo ?

Comment: Running Chrome 18.0.1025.162 m, Windows, GMT +2: the results are reproducible. But explicitly specifying the time in the string representation solves the problem. I generally avoid dates from strings because the format support across browsers is varied and poorly documented, milliseconds are a lot more reliable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking in [V8's source code](http://code.google.com/searchframe#W9JxUuHYyMg/trunk/src/dateparser-inl.h&l=47):

```
// Specification:
// Accept ES5 ISO 8601 date-time-strings or legacy dates compatible
// with Safari.
<...>
//  A string that matches both formats (e.g. 1970-01-01) will be
//  parsed as an ES5 date-time string - which means it will default
//  to UTC time-zone. That's unavoidable if following the ES5
//  specification.
```

Reading the surrounding code, it seems that a date-time string with both month and day 2 symbols long is considered a valid ES5 date-time string. Further down in the ES5 parser, after it parses the dates and times, there's a comment:

```
// Successfully parsed ES5 Date Time String. Default to UTC if no TZ given.
```

In case of "YYYY-MM-DD", once the code gets that far, the ES5 parser has successfully parsed the entire string, so it returns before the legacy parser gets a chance to localize the timezone. Otherwise (month/day are one symbol long) it's treated as a "legacy" datetime and the legacy parser gets to deal with it and localize it.

Answer (score 3):

relaying on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488313/javascripts-getdate-returns-wrong-date), it seems that the `Date`'s string argument constructor is implementation sensitive, due to various `Date.parse()` implementations by browsers.

your measurements are correct, and you probably should avoid using this constructor altogether, if you wish your browser to parse EST correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplified answer drawing from the other answers.

**Date recognizes different string formats**

- Nonstandard dates
- RFC 2282 dates
- ES 5 dates

**Most formats are interpreted as local dates**

On page 14 of [RFC 2282](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt), we see:

> The date and time-of-day SHOULD express local time.

Nonstandard dates are treated in similar fashion.

**ES 5 format is interpreted as UTC**

In [section 15.9.1.15](http://es5.github.com/x15.9.html#x15.9.1.15) of the ES 5 spec we see:

> The value of an absent time zone offset is “Z”.

"Z" represents UTC time.

**The tenth of October**

ES 5 formatted dates require double-digit months and days. The months and days in the original post are not zero-padded. "2020-9-9" is not a valid ES 5 date representation; it's a non-standard format, so it's interpreted in local time. "2020-10-10" *is* a valid ES 5 date representation, so it must be interpreted in UTC.

**Possible workarounds**

- *Don't use the string constructor / Date.parse!*
- Change the separator character so the format never matches the ES 5 format.
- Specify a timezone.
- Adjust dates to local time. If they have hours or minutes: `date.setMinutes(date.getTimezoneOffset());` (this seems to work, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Using "-" as a date separator for USA dates confuses some browsers, some will perform date arithmetic others will return NaN, so use the "/" date separator. A culture aware solution is to use date.js, which is an outstanding JavaScript date handler that resolves issues like the one you have pointed out (http://www.datejs.com/). Using the parse method removes all confusion:

```
Date.parse("2020-12-15").toString() // yields the correct date ("Tue Dec 15 00:00:00 PST 2020").
```

Comment: Try using "/" instead of "-".

Comment: GGG was right in down voting my answer. I should have elaborated and have now done so.

Comment: Oops GGG - sorry, but I did deserve it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the date constructor requires spaces rather than '-'. Its the recommended way. Check out this link:
[3.3. Date and Time Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14)

> Though foldingwhite space is permitted throughout the date-time
> specification, it    is RECOMMENDED that a single space be used in
> each place that FWS    appears (whether it is required or optional)

Also check out this link: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> dateString: String value representing a date. The string should be in a
> format recognized by the parse method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822
> timestamps).

I tried following code and it returns true

```
dateFromNumbers = new Date(2020, 11, 15);
dateFromString = new Date("2020 12 15");
alert(+dateFromNumbers == +dateFromString);​
```

Also its not a problem start with the month of October, it has do with the double digit months. If I try the same method with September then:

```
dateFromNumbers = new Date(2020, 8, 15);
dateFromString = new Date("2020-09-15");
alert(+dateFromNumbers == +dateFromString);​ // This returns false
```

But if I use single digit for September then it returns true

```
dateFromNumbers = new Date(2020, 8, 15);
dateFromString = new Date("2020-9-15");
alert(+dateFromNumbers == +dateFromString);​ // This returns true
```

And if use space with double digit September, then it returns true

```
dateFromNumbers = new Date(2020, 8, 15);
dateFromString = new Date("2020 09 15");
alert(+dateFromNumbers == +dateFromString);​//This returns true
```